# Conditional Probabilities In Sequential Experiments

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability

Let's assume we are given a coin with no information about its bias ($P(H)$ is unknown) or independence ($P(H|T)$ may or may not be equal to $P(H)$, we only know that $P(H) + P(T) = 1$. Let's assume we toss the coin *a sufficient number of times* and are asked to estimate $P(H|T)$. That is the probability of getting heads *after* getting tails. How should we calculate the above probability?

1. Can we group the outcomes in exclusive pairs or should we apply a rolling window of two to the sequence?

The results will be different based on the above decision. Assume, we see the following sequence:
....HHTT..... if we group HH and TT separately, the count of HT will be different than if we estimate the counts on a rolling basis (HH, HT, TT).

2. Why doesn't the law of conditional probabilities $P(A|B) =\frac{P(A, B)}{P(B)}$ apply here?

Comment: What is the underlying probability model?  Are you assuming this is a Markov chain? Two states or more than two? Why do you say that conditional probability does not apply?

Comment: @Michael We do not know anything about the underlying model.

Comment: Then the conditional probability you seek could change over time.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the law of conditional probabilities $P(A|B) =\frac{P(A, B)}{P(B)}$ apply here?

It does apply.

Assume that:

- You have a sequence of $m+1$ coin tosses.
- In the first $m$ of these coin tosses, there were $n$ T's.  Here, when enumerating the number of T's, the very last coin toss is automatically ignored.
- In this sequence there were $a$ occurrences of TH and $b$ occurrences of TT, where $(a + b) = n.$ In this enumeration, if the next to last element of the sequence is a T, then the last element of the sequence is considered, when enumerating the number of occurrences of either TH or TT.

So, there were $(m)$ opportunities for the TH sequence to occur, and it occurred $(a)$ times.

Therefore, $~\displaystyle p(T,H) = \frac{a}{m}.$

Similarly, $~\displaystyle p(T,T) = \frac{b}{m}.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle p(H|T) = \frac{p(T,H)}{p(T,H) + p(T,T)} = \frac{\frac{a}{m}}{\frac{a}{m} + \frac{b}{m}} = \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{a}{n}.$

Further, the $~\displaystyle \frac{a}{n}~$ computation may be alternatively intuited as follows:  Since the T occurred $(n)$ times, there were $(n)$ opportunities for the TH to occur, and it occurred in $a$ of these opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: If you want to estimate $P(H | T)$, this is equal to (the number of times that an H occurred immediately after a T) divided by (the number of times that a T occurred). Therefore, it is equal to the number of times you get an TH sequence divided by the number of times you get a T.

so, if you had T, H, T, T, H, the estimate would be 2/3.

In your specific example with H, H, T, T, it would be 0/1 = 0 because you can't count the last T because you didn't see the one after the last T.

Comment: What is the probability of $P(H|H) in  H, H, H, T? Is it 2/3 or 1/2? If 2/3, does that not violate the independence of the samples? Since we double count the heads in between?

Comment: The probability is 2/3 because there were 2 cases where there was an H after an H so that's the numerator. The denominator is 3 because there were 3 chances for there to be an H after an H. So, 2/3. I don't see where we are double counting ? The probability is always defined as the number of ways where the event of interest actually occurred  ( an H and then another H which is 2 )  divided by the total number of ways that  the event had a chance of occurring ( 3 because there were 3 heads  ).